# Did The Amazing Spider-Man 2 hint a big Spider-Man movie?

Tags: spider-man, marvel, the-amazing-spider-man-2

**Possible spoilers for The Amazing Spider-Man 2**

> Near the end of the movie, we saw Harry at the Ravencroft Institute, where said he wanted to get  a gang together. He said that he needed a small number (6, like in [sinister six](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinister_Six) is small). He said that all they need is already at Oscorp
>  
>  Then, when we see the secret projects at Oscorp, we see the wings of Vulture, the tentacles of Dr. Octopus, and Rhino's costume. All these along with Electro, have been in Sinister Six.

So,

> Could this mean that this movie hinted a Sinister Six movie?

Comment: I sure hope so. I’m tired of these small, independent, two-and-a-half-hour Spider-Man movies with 3 main villains and a production budget of 250 million dollars.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Magic Eight Ball says… **Signs point to Yes**.

Sony announced last year that they were planning to make spin-off movies based on Spiderman villains, which includes Venom and The Sinister Six. Here’s [an article about the news from Deadline](http://www.deadline.com/2013/12/spider-man-spinoffs-sony-marc-webb-alex-kurtzman-roberto-orci-jeff-pinkner-ed-solomon-drew-goddard/):

> Michael Lynton said last month that they intended to create “a bigger universe around Spider-Man” and today Sony Pictures  had a new webslinging big bang. Sony Pictures Entertainment, in association with Marvel Entertainment, announced it will make movies on Spidey villains Venom and The Sinister Six.

That story was published in December 2013. Since then, articles have been posted about the director, screenwriter, and speculation about the members of the group. (Google around if you want details.)

General consensus is that the group is at least partially made up of those seen at the end of *AS2*, so it’s probably teasing this movie, yes.

Comment: so who would fight them?  Or do they just win?

Comment: @Oldcat: It won’t be a straight good vs evil film; it’s a little different to that. (Potential spoilers) http://uk.ign.com/articles/2014/04/11/the-sinister-six-is-a-tale-of-redemption/